# libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

Tags: python, linux, wkhtmltopdf

I get this error when I try to run wkhtmltopdf command from my python script

```
/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set
```

Comment: It's not an answer (we need more details), but I had a similar problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57396756/gnuplot-error-undefined-symbol-ft-property-set) that was caused by a conflicting library loaded due to Tecplot. If others have this problem, check your `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for `libfreetype.so.6`.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issue and the comment of @Ross led me on the correct way. The library `libfreetype.so.6` was not accessible through the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Fixing this resolved the issue.