# Gnuplot Error: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot, freetype

I'm having trouble running gnuplot 5.2 on my desktop (Ubuntu 18.04). I get the following error:

```
$ gnuplot

    G N U P L O T
    Version 5.2 patchlevel 2    last modified 2017-11-01 

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2017
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')

Terminal type is now 'qt'
gnuplot> test
/usr/lib/gnuplot/gnuplot_qt: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set

Warning: slow font initializationgnuplot> 
gnuplot>
```

I have tried `upgrade`-ing gnuplot using `apt` to no avail, and I'm not sure what else to try.

I found a similar question with no answers here: [libQt5XcbQpa.so.5: undefined symbol: FT_Property_Set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799936/libqt5xcbqpa-so-5-undefined-symbol-ft-property-set)

### Edit

My gnuplot depends on libfreetype6, which is installed but apparently incorrectly. The installed libfreetype is:

```
$ apt-file list libfreetype6
libfreetype6: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
...
```

According to `nm` that library contains no symbols:

```
$ nm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6
nm: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6: no symbols
```

But using `strings` it does contain what's missing:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so.6 | grep FT_Property_Set
FT_Property_Set
```

So it seems like I just need to point gnuplot to the correct location containing `libfreetype`? What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Not a gnuplot error.  It likely indicates a missing or incompatible version of libfreetype, loaded dynamically by the Qt runtime.

Comment: @Ethan Yes, it seems you're right - can you check the edit?

Comment: Wrong tool. Try `strings /whereveritis/libfreetype.so.6 | grep FT_Prop`.
You probably should look for help on an Ubuntu forum.

Comment: Ok, I will post there if I can't resolve it here. @ethan, do you know what gnuplot uses to determine the library locations? I tried `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` but it didn't work. Edited the main also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting an answer here so others can find it in the future. The issue was a conflicting other version of `libfreetype` from a Tecplot installation.

That version was slightly different (does not include `FT_Property_Set`, at least) and was getting loaded first. Unloading Tecplot, or unsetting that portion of my `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, worked for me.